# jQuery mobile page link not working

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

In my jQuery mobile (v 1.2) web site, I have several separate pages (i.e. each page has one header, content and footer). The problem is I can't link the pages. The following line is not working.
`<a href="anotherpage.html">Another Page</a>` shows "Error loading page".

If I add `rel="external"` to the `<a>` element, it works. However, it turns off the automatic loading via Ajax. But I want to use the Ajax loading as well as keep the pages separate. Just wondering whether it's possible.

**Code Page 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>Single page template</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">  </script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">   
            <a href="b.html"> click me</a>
        </div>  
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Footer content</h4>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Page 2**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>Single page template</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">      </script>
 </head> 
 <body> 
     <div data-role="page">
         <div data-role="header">
             <h1>Page 2</h1>
         </div>
         <div data-role="content">  
              page 2 content
         </div> 
         <div data-role="footer">
             <h4>Footer content</h4>
         </div>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure your page hierarchy is correct? Alternatively, you can try using absolute URLs

Comment: Show us as example of your page. This is simply not enough.

Comment: When you click the link, is the url in your address bar the url you were expecting?  ie, is it trying to link within a sub directory or something but the file you want is on the root?  Can't think of a more logical explanation than that...

Comment: @Adam  Page hierarchy is correct. Both pages are in the same directory.

Comment: @user1988856 if you can't post the exact code you're using for the page and the link itself, we can't help.

Comment: @Mike when I click the link, chrome shows the url at the bottom of the page which is `file///C:/Documents and Settings/Adam/Desktop/a.html`

Comment: @AdamD added the full code

Comment: I got it. For some weird reason it doesn't work in Chrome but works in Firefox.

Comment: @AdamD It also doesn't make any sense to me. I spent a few hours to solve this problem. It's really not working in Chrome (running on Win XP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to load your pages from the filesystem.
Chrome settings prevents that, assuming that a security risk.

Serve your pages with a web server. You can use IIS on Windows XP Pro for that.

or

You can start chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-file` command line option

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are supposed to give each 'data-role="page" and id like "page2 so in effect it would be:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page"> <!--Home Page-->
<div data-role="page" id="page2"> <!--2nd Page-->
<div data-role="page" id="page3"> <!--3rd Page-->
```

Im not sure if that is what you are looking for in this case though...